# How to filter out a dataframe with another dataframe's values and collect statistics based on number of occurences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dataframes and I want to match df1 with df2 to see if any values in df1 are in df2. In addition, count how many times the values match. Finally I want to send those statistics to a new dataframe.

Here is a breakdown:

df1:

```
df1=['abc','cba']
```

df2:

```
df2=['abc','cba','abc123', 'abc', 'abc']
```

I want the new dataframe's output to look like:

```
match, count
'abc', 3
'cba', 1
```

As you can see, my new dataframe displays the value that matched from df1 and how many times it matched in df2.

Here is my python so far:

```
 import pandas as pd
ls1 = ['abc', 'cba']
ls2 = ['abc', 'cba', 'abc123', 'abc', 'abc','cba']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ls1, columns=['senders'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ls2, columns=['sender2'])
#print(df1)
#print(df2)

a = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['senders'], right_on=['sender2']).value_counts(['senders'])
print(a)
```

Here is my output:

```
senders
abc        3
cba        2
dtype: int64
```

However, I want the new data frame to be renamed to match, count and then their stats respectively.

I know my code isn't much but I am new to python and dataframes so I am completely lost so any ideas or suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
import pandas as pd

df1=['abc','cba']
df2=['abc','cba','abc123', 'abc', 'abc']

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

dataframe['match'] = df2
new_dataframe = 
dataframe.loc[dataframe.match.isin(df1)].groupby('match').size().to_frame(name = 
'count').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using DataFrame for this a requirement?  If you want a (very) quick calculation that doesn't involve pandas, try:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([e for e in ls2 if e in frozenset(ls1)])
```

Comment: That works but is there any way to put headers on it- match, count?